# Form not displaying in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

So I have a page using PHP and a MySQL query. What I'm wanting to do is create basically an "edit" page that takes data from my database and uses it to show the values in various inputs. The user can then change the data in the input which will then update the corresponding MySQL table row. However, for whatever reason the page is NOT displaying the form, but rolling over to the `else` statement. I can verify the $_SESSION['weaponName'] is working, because it will echo the correct thing. Any ideas on why the form will not show up for me?

#### edit.php

```
   <?php
session_start();

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db_name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$weaponName = $_SESSION['weaponName'];

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM weapons limit 1");

if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>=1){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $creator= $row['creator'];
    $weaponCategory= $row['weaponCategory'];
    $weaponSubCategory= $row['weaponSubCategory'];
    $costAmount= $row['costAmount'];
    $costType= $row['costType'];
    $damageS= $row['damageS'];
    $damageM= $row['damageM'];
    $critical= $row['critical'];
    $rangeIncrement= $row['rangeIncrement'];
    $weight= $row['weight'];
    $weaponType= $row['weaponType'];
    $masterwork= $row['masterwork'];
    $attributes= $row['attributes'];
    $specialAbilities= $row['specialAbilities'];
    $additionalInfo= $row['additionalInfo'];
}

?>

<form action="weaponEditUpdate.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="weaponName" value="<?php echo $weaponName;?>">

    Weapon Name: <input type="text" name="weaponName" value="<?php echo $weaponName;?>">
    <br>
    Weapon Category: <select name="weaponCategory">
    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['weaponCategory'] ."'>" . $row['weaponCategory'] ."</option>";
    } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="Submit" value="Change">
</form>

<?php
}else{
    echo 'No entry found. <a href="javascript:history.back()">Go back</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Right off the bat, you're mixing `mysqli_` with `mysql_` so that's a no go. You're connecting with `mysqli_` but querying with `mysql_`

Comment: What's wrong with an array? Just change your `if` to `if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))` and remove the while loop. You have all the information you need in the `$row` variable.

Comment: (FYI)=> There are just too many things wrong with this code, which is why I didn't bother putting in an answer.

Comment: Hey my bad i completely forgot I was connecting with mysqli. I know, retarded. Anyways I have taken all your advice but still no luck. Also, if I use simply just the `if` statement as mentioned by @jeroen the page is just blank. Please excuse my ignorance. In case any one had any other thoughts on this I have updated the code to show changes made.

Comment: I don't see any changes here. Edit: ah, here we go, it just kicked in.

Comment: You'd still need to change to the mysqli variant of the function (I just copied your code to illustrate)...

Comment: @Fred-ii- changes made.

Comment: Instead of `if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>=1){` can you try `if(mysqli_num_rows($query) >0){` @Aldentec or `if(mysqli_num_rows($query) ==1){`

Comment: `if(mysqli_num_rows($query) >0){` did the trick. Thank you so much @fred -ii-

Comment: Can you post that as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Plus, you may also need to add `$weaponName = $_POST['weaponName'];` @Aldentec

Comment: Just did, glad it got resolved :) @Aldentec and you're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by OP (from comment conversations)

Instead of

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>=1){
```

use

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) >0){
```

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM weapons limit 1");
```

to

```
 $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM weapons limit 1");
```

BUT omg all your code is mysql while you connected by mysqli  !! .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790692/form-not-displaying-in-php#comment32970742_21790692

Comment: Then for `<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))` ;-) too many things wrong with the question, which is why I didn't bother.

Comment: Thanks, I put up some rather long ones sometime lol - and you seem like a nice guy too. I'm from Canada, just outside Ottawa, and you? and thanks for the badge :)

Comment: I deleted comments also. Sweden, nice place, from the many photos, documentaries I've seen. Somewhere I'd want to visit.

Comment: There are many beautiful places here. One of which I enjoy visiting (been there 2 times) is the Maritimes. Nova Scotia, Gaspesie, Prince Edward Island etc. and Quebec is a beautiful province. The people here are very nice :)

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, very beautiful surroundings. Mountains, rivers, lakes :)

Comment: Oh ok lol I meant that the people are friendly, yet yes... some are beautiful too hahaha a bit of both ;-)

Comment: You too, have a great day/evening. It's evening here now. Take care my friend :)

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing functions

```
mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db_name");
```

Won't work with

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM weapons limit 1");
```

Try

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM weapons limit 1");
```

And then

```
if($query->num_rows >= 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You connect with [mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli), which is fine. THEN, you attempt to run queries via [mysql](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php). Those are two separate extensions. You can't mix them as they won't "communicate" with one another. Stick to mysqli.